# A minimal eigenvalue inequality for Positive Definite Matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Does this statement hold?

If $$ \lambda_{\min}(B)\leq \lambda_{\min}(C),$$ then
$$ \lambda_{\min}(BA)\leq \lambda_{\min}(CA),$$
where $A,B,C$ are symmetric Positive Definite Matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are easy counterexamples with  $2 \times 2$ diagonal matrices.